# How to push json keys and json values into two arrays

Tags: javascript, json

I have one json file with following structure:

```
{
    "won":3,
    "lost":0,
    "void":0,
    "active":1
}
```

I've been trying to figure out how to make two arrays in javascript that will contain following information:

```
var labels = ["won", "lost", "void", "active"];
var data = ["3","0", "0","1"];
```

But I can't my head around how to do it.

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
var labels = Object.keys(input);
var data = Object.values(input);
```

However you should check the browsers compatibility:

[`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)
[`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)

Comment: (Remember to parse the JSON first)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```js
var item_list = {
    "won":3,
    "lost":0,
    "void":0,
    "active":1
};

var labels = [];
var data = [];
for(var item in item_list){
 // console.log(item);
  labels.push(item);
  data.push(item_list[item]);
}

console.log(labels);
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this too

```js
var mydata = {
    "won":3,
    "lost":0,
    "void":0,
    "active":1
};

var first = [],
    second = [];

for (var property in mydata) {

   if ( ! mydata.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
      continue;
   }

   first.push(property);
   second.push(mydata[property]);

}

console.log(first);
console.log(second);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```js
var obj = {
    "won":3,
    "lost":0,
    "void":0,
    "active":1
}
var keys = new Array();
var values = new Array();

for (var key in obj) {
  keys.push(key)
  values.push(obj[key]);
}

console.log(keys);
console.log(values);
```